# NetSuite SS2.0 - Create a File with "addtimestamptourl" checked

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Looking here for a way to set the GENERATE URL TIME STAMP field (`addtimestamptourl`) to checked using SS2.0 as part of rendering a PDF.

Currently I have:

```
var fPDF = renderer.renderAsPdf();
fPDF.name = fName;
fPDF.addtimestamptourl = true;
fPDF.folder = fFolder;
var fileId = fPDF.save();
```

I have also tried

`fPDF.addtimestamptourl = 'T';`

With no success so far, the box remains unchecked on the file record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot set `addtimestamptourl` property to true using SuiteScript.

Also, `renderer.renderAsPdf()` returns `file.File` object and file object does not have property to set `addtimestamptourl` as per NetSuite help docs for [files module](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4247974825.html). As of now, NetSuite does not seems to allow setting/updating property of file in file cabinet.